# Tefillin as an Ot

Tags: tefilin, symbols-symbology, hands-fingers

The commandment of the arm-tefillin is וקשרתם לאות על ידך, "And you shall bind it as an sign upon your *yad*". ([Devarim 6:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9970#v=8), [Devarim 11:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9975#v=18)) However, having just read an [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51364/4504) by Shalom, defining a similar question, I wondered which part of the tefillin the sign was.

Is the sign of the tefillin the four parshiot [in the bayit on the biceps], or is it the retzu'ah wrapping on the hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I think it's the *bayis*, rather than the *retzuah*. Here are some reasons why:**

Rashi writes ([Devarim 6:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9970#showrashi=true&v=8)):

> וקשרתם לאות על ידך: אלו תפילין שבזרוע
>
> And you shall tie them for a sign on your hand: these are the tefillin
>   of the forearm

It sounds like the part of the תפילין של יד that is the sign is the part that goes on the forearm; however, I'm not sure if this is a good proof, because the whole tefillin is called "tefillin of the forearm;" the word "זרוע" here might just come to differentiate this tefillin from the head-tefillin.

The בעל הטורים, there, writes:

> ידך. בגי' גובה היד
>
> Your hand: on the height (higher part) of the hand

Again, this sounds like the אות is the part on the זרוע, the forearm.

The best proof I found to say that the "sign" is the *bayis* is in the תרגום יונתן, [chapter 6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_(%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F)_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D#.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7_.D7.95), verse 8:

> וְתִקְטוּרִינוּן לְאָתִין כְּתִיבִין עַל יְדָךְ דִּשְמָאלָא
>
> And you will tie this for a written sign on your left hand

Of the two parts you mentioned, the only one that could possibly be a "written" sign is the *bayis* of the tefillin.

(*all translations mine*)